# UiWebView not displaying responsive webpages

Tags: ios, responsive-design, uiwebview

I'm trying to display webpages in UIWebView. But it's not displaying the web pages properly. All the webpages are responsive.

Below is my code

```
_webview.delegate = self;
[self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_webURL]]];
[_activityLoading startAnimating];

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    [_activityLoading stopAnimating];
    [_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'width=%d;', false); ", (int)webView.frame.size.width]];
}
```

[image: Sample Webpage]
[image: Proper formatted]

It's displaying properly in Safari.

Please help

Comment: Please give the detail of "not displaying properly" by either screenshots or detail description.

Comment: Please check. I had added a sample image.

Comment: is webview "scalesPageToFit" property set to YES?

Comment: @SuryaSubenthiran it didn't help

Comment: How would the others know what should the proper one looks like?

Comment: @zcui93 As you can see in the image that the page does not contain any formatting. I had uploaded the image for proper one too

Comment: It finally starts to become a clear question. Are you trying to only load the webpages wrote by yourself? If that's the case, it might be helpful to show the header of your `html` file. If not, can you confirm it's not working with other webpages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device on which it was getting improper was having iOS 9.3. After upgrading xCode it worked properly. Didn't get any other problem related to UIWebView there after.